# How can I convert a PHP function's parameter list to an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, parameters, arguments, associative

I want to convert the arguments to a function into an **associative array** with keys equal to the parameter variable names, and values equal to the parameter values.

PHP:

```
function my_function($a, $b, $c) {

    // <--- magic goes here to create the $params array

    var_dump($params['a'] === $a); // Should result in bool(true)
    var_dump($params['b'] === $b); // Should result in bool(true)
    var_dump($params['c'] === $c); // Should result in bool(true)
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just define the initial function to accept an array as the first argument and feed an array?

Comment: meder: That would 1) provide an ugly API, and 2) require a lot of changes to calling source. Many of these functions already exist and are being called.

Comment: I don't really see why it would be an "ugly" API - to me it would be cleaner and akin to feeding dictionaries as arguments in Python and feeding objects in ECMAScript.

Comment: it makes the documentation clearer and lets PHP enforce that each function is passed the correct number/type of arguments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The you can do this using [`compact`](http://php.net/compact):

```
function myFunc($a, $b, $c) {
    $params = compact('a', 'b', 'c');
    // ...
}
```

Or, [`get_defined_vars()`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) will give you an associative array of all the variables defined in that scope, which would work, but I think this might also include `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc...

Otherwise, you can use [`func_get_args`](http://au.php.net/func_get_args) to get a list of all the arguments passed to the function. This is *not* associative though, since it is only data which is passed (that is, there's no variable names). This also lets you have any number of arguments in your function.

Or, just specify one argument, which is an array:

```
function myFunc($params) {

}
```

`compact()` seems to be closest to what you're after though.

Comment: The reason I don't like this is the variable names have to be repeated.

Comment: look at `get_defined_vars` then.

Answer (score 10):

[get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/get_defined_vars) is what you need if no other vars are defined before its called inside the function (you can ensure this by making it the first thing you do inside the function).

```
function my_function($a, $b, $c) {

    $params = get_defined_vars(); // <--- create the $params array

    var_dump($params['a'] === $a); // results in bool(true)
    var_dump($params['b'] === $b); // results in bool(true)
    var_dump($params['c'] === $c); // results in bool(true)
}
```

Comment: This convenient with [spreading the last parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75658700/2943403) as well.

Answer (score 4):

I upvoted @nickf's answer but would like to add that that compact() is also a great way to instantiate a model using a ctor:

```
class User {
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;

    public function __construct ( $email, $password, $firstName, $lastName )
    {
        foreach ( compact( array_keys( (array)$this )) as $k => $v )
            $this->$k = $v;
    }
}
```

Just make sure that the params have the exact same spelling as the fields.

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested, but not implemented: you can use [`Reflection`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to gather the parameter names, then associate those with the values:

```
function args_to_assoc_array($function, $args) {                                 
    if (false === strpos($function, '::')) {                                     
        $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($function);                         
    } else {                                                                     
        $reflection = new ReflectionMethod(...explode('::', $function));         
    }                                                                            
    $assoc = [];                                                                 
    foreach ($reflection->getParameters() as $i => $parameter) {                 
        $assoc[$parameter->getName()] = $args[$i];                               
    }                                                                            
    return $assoc;                                                               
}
```

Then you can call this in the same way, whether in a function or a method:

```
function f($x, $y) { return args_to_assoc_array(__METHOD__, func_get_args()); }
class A {                                                                     
    function m($z) { return args_to_assoc_array(__METHOD__, func_get_args()); }
}                                                                             
var_dump(f(7, 2), (new A)->m(4));
```

[which outputs](https://3v4l.org/M5t7X):

```
array(2) {
  ["x"]=>
  int(7)
  ["y"]=>
  int(2)
}
array(1) {
  ["z"]=>
  int(4)
}
```

I've not timed it, but I strongly suspect this is much much slower than using `compact`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 8+ named arguments

```
class User
{
    private string $email;
    private string $password;
    public string $firstName;
    protected string $lastName;

    public function __construct(...$arguments)
    {

        setterObject($this, ...$arguments);

        var_dump('email: ' . $this->email);
        var_dump('password: ' . $this->password);
        var_dump($this->firstName);
        var_dump($this->lastName);


    }
}

new User(email:'xxxxx@email.com', password: '#@some@password@_', firstName: 'firstName', lastName: 'lastName');

function setterObject(object $obj, mixed ...$arguments)
{
    $args = get_defined_vars()['arguments'];
    //just named arguments
    if (count(array_filter(array_keys($args), 'is_string')) ===count($args) ) {
        array_map(function ($prop) use ($obj,$args ) {
            $prop->setAccessible(true);
            if(!is_null($args[$prop->getName()])) {
                $prop->setValue($obj, $args[$prop->getName()]);
            }
        }, (new ReflectionObject($obj))->getProperties());
    }else{
        throw new Exception('the object was not initialized');
    }
}
```