# Join two flat, indexed arrays (by index) to form an indexed array of associative rows with hardcoded keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, associative-array

Here are my two arrays:

```
Array (
    [0] => https://google.com/
    [1] => https://bing.com/
)
    
Array (
    [0] => Google
    [1] => Bing
)
```

Here's the output that I want in JSON:

```
[
    {
        "url": "https://google.com/",
        "name": "Google"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://bing.com/",
        "name": "Bing"
    }
]
```

I'm not able to get both the array in foreach loop and using json_encode to print them in JSON format.

Comment: Hint: use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) (with `true` as the second argument) to parse the expected JSON then work out how to build that data structure using your input. Hint #2: use [`array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Comment: @Kalui keep in mind that if you got the answer that satisfies your question, please consider to upvote, and mark the answer that helps you more like the right one by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this solution requires both arrays *(in my case $domains and $names)* have the entries in the same order.

```
$domains = [
    'https://google.com/',
    'https://bing.com/'
];

$names = [
    'Google',
    'Bing'
];

$output = [];

// Iterate over the domains
foreach($domains as $key => $value){
    // And push into the $output array
    array_push(
        $output,
        // A new array that contains
        [
            // the current domain in the loop
            "url" => $value,
            // and the name, in the same index as the domain.
            "name" => $names[$key]
        ]
    );

}

// Finally echo the JSON output.
echo json_encode($output);

// The above line will output the following:
//[
//    {
//        "url": "https://google.com/",
//        "name": "Google"
//    },
//    {
//        "url": "https://bing.com/",
//        "name": "Bing"
//    }
//]
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$urls = [
    'https://google.com/',
    'https://bing.com/'
];

$names = [
    'Google',
    'Bing'
];

$combined = array_map(
  fn($url, $name) => ['url' => $url, 'name' => $name],
  $urls,
  $names
);

echo(json_encode($combined));
```

Of course, the arrays need to have the same number of elements, in the same order.
See it [in action](https://3v4l.org/9rs88).

---

#### Remark

The [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) (`fn($url, $name) => ['url' => $url 'name' => $name]`) works only on PHP 7.4 and newer versions.
For older versions use the full syntax for [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```php
function($url $name) { 
  return ['url' => $url, 'name' => $name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more elegant than axiac's snippet, you can make mapped calls of `get_defined_vars()` which means that you'll only need to mention the new keys by name in the anonymous function's signature.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aJpeK))

```
$urls = [
    'https://google.com/',
    'https://bing.com/'
];

$names = [
    'Google',
    'Bing'
];

echo json_encode(
         array_map(
             fn($url, $name) => get_defined_vars(),
             $urls,
             $names
         ),
         JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
     );
```

See an earlier page on the topic of converting parameters and their values to an associative array: [How can I convert a PHP function's parameter list to an associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1419467/2943403)